# php call sphinx, total found is 2, but matches is empty, why?

Tags: php, sphinx

php call sphinx, total found is 2, but matches is empty, why?

php package: https://pecl.php.net/package/sphinx version:1.3.3
sphinx version:2.0.1

when I query('@author tairyao', '*'), the result is:

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [warning] => 
    [status] => 0
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => author
            [1] => title
            [2] => description
        )

    [attrs] => Array
        (
        )

    [matches] => Array
        (
            [102373] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 7702
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [102428] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 7702
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [total] => 2
    [total_found] => 2
    [time] => 0
    [words] => Array
        (
            [tairyao] => Array
                (
                    [docs] => 4
                    [hits] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

The total and total_found are all 2, why attrs is empty?

Comment: Does the index actually have any attributes on it? But also you only get attributes in all the indexed being searched. Might be better specify a specific index, rather than '*'...

Comment: you’re right，if I use indexA, the attrs is correct, but if I use *, the attrs is empty. I think the problem is on the pecl api. Because if I use the api file in the Sphinx tar package, all are right.